# Page not found when signing up for StackOverflow using sound Captcha

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha, sign-up

I was registering for a stack overflow account and encountered a problem.

I was using a sound captcha. No account was created when I submitted the form, but I was able to (obviously) create an account using the text captcha.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This probably had nothing to do with the sound captcha, actually.  It looks like openid.se decided you were already logged in for some reason, not entirely sure what happened there.

I've deployed some potential fixes, and more logging (and better user facing error messages, "Not Found" is garbage I apologize for).

Comment: +1 for making stuff better

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I simply got the error you get. It was a cookies problem. For the duration of the sign in, you have to allow *everything*.

Comment: [Cookies are a fundamental requirement for using the site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need), actually.

Comment: @CodyGray: Yeah, obviously. But I have my browser set to "accept cookies only from the site I visit". This is usually sufficient for SE sites to work, once you are logged in, but the sign in process apparently required more. The error message ("Page not found") is still not very helpful.

Comment: Agreed, but Kevin's answer suggests that he improved the error messages.

Comment: @CodyGray: Which is evidently not the case.